# PHP mysql class not inserting

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code:

```
class mysql {

public $mysql;

function __construct($host, $user, $pass, $db){
    $this->mysql = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $db);

    if($this->mysql->connect_errno)
        exit('Error connecting to the database');
}

public function replace(array $var){
    $str = "";
    foreach($var as $k => $v){
        $str .= substr_replace($v, "'", 0) . substr_replace ($v, "',", -1);
    }
    $str[strlen($str)-1] = "";
    return $str;
}

public function insert($table, array $kv){
    $p1 = implode(',', array_keys($kv));
    $p2 = $this->replace($kv);
    $q = "INSERT INTO $table ($p1) VALUES ($p2)";
    echo $q;
    echo $this->mysql->query($q);

}


}
```

And I use the function and no data is inserted to database I cant se anything on DB

Output of echo:

```
INSERT INTO users (username,password,email) VALUES ('Hi','Hwghrwhw','WREHRWWRWRGH')
```

Comment: where is your connection and insert query?

Comment: Sorry i posted wrong paste now is replaced, reload

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem of your code is the missing escaping of your colnames

```
INSERT INTO `users` (`username`,`password`,`email`) VALUES ('Hi','Hwghrwhw','WREHRWWRWRGH')
```

PASSWORD is a protected keyword. Here your changed code:

```
public function insert($table, array $kv){
    $p1 = implode('`,`', array_keys($kv));
    $p2 = $this->replace($kv);
    $q = "INSERT INTO `$table` (`$p1`) VALUES ($p2)";
    echo $q;
    echo $this->mysql->query($q);
}
```